# Adding Parameters to calling a class prevents it's opening of new window method from working. Java FX

Tags: java, class, oop, javafx, fxml

When passing parameters through the calling of a new class from the controller, it seems that the existence of parameters prevents the class from carrying out it's method of opening a new window correctly (a method that exists within the called class that opens a new window). However, when re-creating example data within the class within the initialize method and not passing through the parameters, calling the class and its new window creation method works okay.

The building of a table/graphs methods etc are called within the initialise method of the new class. The creation of a new window is a method that is called within the controller after the class itself has been initialised.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Main:
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Example"); //set the name of the title
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1200, 750)); //width and height of pane
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

Controller:package sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Controller {

    public Controller() {
    }
    public void openWin() {
//         Example Data Set
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (double j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            ArrayList<Double> exampleDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
            exampleDataSet.add(j);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Random r = new Random();
                double randomValue = 0 + (100 - 0) * r.nextDouble();
                exampleDataSet.add(randomValue);
            }
            data.add(exampleDataSet);
        }
        //Example Headers for Data Set
        String headers = "Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4, Header5";
        //Open New Window (this is upon button click)
        Win newWin = new Win(headers, data);
        newWin.openNewWin();
    }

//
//

}
```

```
Win Class:package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Win {
    @FXML private TableView<ObservableList<Double>> tableView = new TableView<>();

    private Stage stage = new Stage();

    String headers[] = null;
    String items[] = null;
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
    ObservableList<ObservableList<Double>> csvData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private String newHeaders;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public Win(String headers, ArrayList data) {
        this.newHeaders = headers;
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void initialize() {
        generateTable(newHeaders, data);
    }

    public void openNewWin() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("win.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setTitle("Table");

            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot load new window");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(newHeaders);
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }
    public void generateTable(String newHeaders, ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> dataset) {
        try {
            System.out.println(newHeaders);
            System.out.println(dataset);
            headers = newHeaders.split(",");
            for (String w : headers) {
                columns.add(w);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
                final int finalIdx = i;
                TableColumn<ObservableList<Double>, Double> column = new TableColumn<>(columns.get(i));
                column.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue().get(finalIdx))); //Set text
                tableView.getColumns().add(column);
            }

            for (ArrayList<Double> array : dataset) {
                ObservableList<Double> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                row.clear();
                for (double number : array) {
                    row.add(number);
                }
                csvData.add(row);
            }
            tableView.setItems(csvData);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
Sample FXML:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane id="gridPane" alignment="top_center" gridLinesVisible="false" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller"> <!--will show gaps between columns, rows & cells-->
    <!-- can use center -->
    <!--forcing width of columns-->
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10" left="30" right="30" top="10" /> <!-- will have a gap between title and below-->
    </padding>

    <Button onAction="#openWin" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="10" text="Exit"/>
</GridPane>

win FXML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane id="gridPane" alignment="top_center" gridLinesVisible="false" hgap="10" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="1000.0" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Win">
    <TableView fx:id="tableView"  GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />

</GridPane>


<!--The Grid Pane for win would include other items like buttons and graphs-->
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: hi @kleopatra thanks, I have added in the full code for a working program. Thanks

Comment: @Andrew kleopatra asked for an MRE (minimum reproducible example) for many reasons. The main one is the site doesn't exist just to help you with your problem, but to use your problem and its answers to help many other people also. To make it understandable, the rules request an MRE rather than the full code of a complex program. Another reason for this is that in the process of making an MRE, you might find the source of the bug yourself and be able to answer your question. A third, very minor reason, is that if you become a professional programmer, you may often be required to make MRE's.

Comment: Ok whatever you are doing here is a little odd. So what I see in your code what should not be done is creating instances of Controllers(here Win) by your self also taking parameters in the constructor of a controller is never done. If you wanna pass parameters to a controller get the instance of the controller from the FXMLLoader by calling the getController() Method.

Comment: In addition to @Alex's comment, you can also call `setController(...)` on the `FXMLLoader` (before calling `load`) and pass in a controller instance. This allows you to have controllers with constructor parameters. (You also need to remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the FXML file to make this work, as that results in the controller being set to the result of calling the *no-argument* constructor on the specified class.) But what you're doing here doesn't make a lot of sense: you're trying to load the FXML from its own controller...